# What is the optimal way to incorporate a filter snapshot inside another firebase snapshot?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filter, snapshot

I am currently incorporating a filter Z inside my snapshot, however it duplicates a `[DataSnapshot]` line. Below is how I am currently doing it with the filter Z part in bold (**). It would be ideal to move the filter Z out of the initial snapshot A onto a different file, but I need access to in order to run the `if countb >= 1` line in the initial snapshot A. Can that be done, and if so, how?

```
 let thisUsersUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid 
    
    refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");
    
    refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: { [weak self]  snapshot in
        
        
        guard let self = self else { return }

        
        
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            
            self.people.removeAll()
            
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] { 
           
                 /////SNAPSHOT A
                
                
                if people.key != thisUsersUid {
                    print("peoplekey",people.key)
                    
                    let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
                    _ = peopleObject?["caption"] as? Int
                    
                    
                    ///Filter Z
                    **let coordSnap1 = people.childSnapshot(forPath: "peopleWhoLike2")
                    let peopleArray = coordSnap1.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                    let filteredResults = peopleArray.filter { person in
                        let personUid = person.value as! Int
                        let coordSnap120 = personUid
                        print("kjk", coordSnap120 )
                        //let secondsInDay = 86400
                        let date1 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(coordSnap120)/1000.0)
                        return Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date1)
                    }**
                     ////END FILTER Z
                    
                    print(filteredResults, "ppp")
                    let countb = filteredResults.compactMap({$0}).count
                    print(countb, "bbb")
                    **if countb >= 1**  {

....
```

Comment: Why do you want to move the code in that function to a different *file* and what's wrong with where it is? Can you clarify and update the question.

Comment: I mean just move it out of the Snapshot A because I thought it might be quicker and more efficient not to have the nested snapshots inside one another.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with nested snapshots, as long as you don't create a race condition or attempt to access data that has not yet been loaded. It's actually very common. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Yes, you can make it in answer form and I'll mark it as solved.